# Total number of ways to arrange the prime divisor of a number so it can be written using M digits

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, permutations

How many ways we can arrange all the prime divisor of a number so it can be written using M factors, where M <=T. T is the total number of prime divisor of the give number N.
Example:N=27, its prime divisor is 3(repeating 3 times, so T=3). Now for a given value M=2. There are 2 ways {(3,9),(9,3)}.

The above problem can be solved using brute force approach for small value. I am trying to figure out a generic formula for the above. Please suggest.

Comment: $9$ is not a prime divisor. For $N=11$, there is $T=1$, hence $M\le T$ implies you want only one digit even though $11$ is a two-digit number?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "how many ways can we arrange all the prime divisors of a number so it can be written using M *factors*? A digit is a numeral $0, 1, ..., 8, 9$. Also, for N = 27, there is only ONE prime divisor, and that being 3.

Comment: Perhaps your question is : How many ways can a number $N$ be written as product of $M$ numbers. Or $M$ factors larger than 1. (And I suppose order of factors counts).

Comment: @amWhy,Maesumi:yeah u guys are getting it right...I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: For your example of $27$, what about $(1,27)$ and $(27,1)$?  Do they count?  It gets easier then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you number is $N$, you can express it as a product of primes to exponents, $N=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\ldots p_n^{e_n}$.  The first thing to notice is that you don't care about the $p_i$, the number of ways will only depend upon the $e_i$

Now you can think about your factors being $M$ buckets that you put the prime factors into, multiplying all the prime factors in each bucket.  The powers of $p_1$ can be distributed in the number of [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $e_1+M$ into $M$ parts.  Each part is at least $1$ and you put one less than the part into the particular bin.  For example, with $e_1=4, M=3$, you can have $7=5+1+1, 4+2+1, 3+2+2, $ and many others.  These would correspond to numbers of factors of $p_1$ split $(4,0,0), (3,1,0), (2,1,1), $ and so on.  The article shows that the number of compositions is then ${e_1+M-1} \choose {M-1}$.  You then multiply all of these terms for each prime, so the total number is $$\prod_i {{e_i+M-1} \choose {M-1}}$$

This will include cases where one or more of the factors is $1$ because a bucket didn't get any factors at all.  It is harder to count those because it makes interactions between the various primes.

Comment: explained well....but if there is restriction that each bucket will hold at least one prime factor F>1.How do u suggest to handle it.

Comment: @rspr:  I would sum over the number of empty buckets.  For one bucket empty, there are M choices for which will be empty, then the same function with M-1 buckets for how to fill the rest.  For two empty, there are M(M-1)/2 ways to choose the empties, then the same function with M-2 buckets to fill the rest.